# Multiple objects in ajax data issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building an app using jQuery/AJAX + Node.js. I have a problem processing multiple objets on the server side. I have 3 objects I want to pass to the server:

```
var store_id = 'some_store_id'
var state_id = 'some_state_id'

var chips = [
    {
        id: 1234,
        brand: 'lays'
    },
    {
        id: 4321,
        brand: 'doritoes'
    },
    {
        id: '1332',
        brand: 'cheetos'
    }
]
```

However, when I try to pass them all at once:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/my_api',
    data: { store_id: store_id, state_id: state_id, chips: chips},
    success: function () {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Data on the server is printed out as:

```
 console.log(req.body)

 {
    store_id = 'some_store_id',
    state_id = 'some_state_id',
    'chips[0][id]': '1234',
    'chips[0][brand]': 'lays',
    'chips[1][id]': '4321',
    'chips[1][brand]': 'doritoes',
    'chips[2][id]: '1332',
    'chips[2][brand] : 'cheetos'
  }
```

This is problematic because I can't do something like `req.body.chips`. I tried to `stringify` the `chips` object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/my_api',
    data: { store_id: store_id, state_id: state_id, chips: JSON.stringify(chips)},
    success: function () {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

But this resulted in `chips` being a string on the server side:

```
  console.log(req.body)

  {
    store_id = 'some_store_id',
    state_id = 'some_state_id',
    chips: '[
        'chips[0][id]': '1234',
        'chips[0][brand]': 'lays',
        'chips[1][id]': '4321',
        'chips[1][brand]': 'doritoes',
        'chips[2][id]: '1332',
        'chips[2][brand] : 'cheetos'
    ]'
  }
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting `dataType` property to `json`.

Comment: that's invalid json you need to create your parser.

Comment: Why not parse the data to a JSON string first? - `var data = JSON.stringify({ store_id: store_id, state_id: state_id, chips: chips});` that way you know you're sending a valid JSON string. The first output example doesn't make sense to me unless jQuery is doing some weird parsing.